# Can I usePhoneGap this way?

Tags: ios, cordova

I want to use phonegap this way:

1. create a iphone project in native, not in phoneGap.
2. create a uiwebview in a view controller
3. use the api of phoneGap in that webview.

Can I do this? Could you summarize the steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.
[Embed PhoneGap in your iOS app](http://devgirl.org/2012/11/15/embed-cordovaphonegap-in-your-native-ios-app/)